# Loading JavaScript code inside body meteor

Tags: meteor

The code only seems to work when I add it to the head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.leadboltmobile.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=00000000"></script>
```

I tried other answers, but they seem to be outdated for meteor 1.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try loading your JS script using jQuery :

```
// Meteor startup triggered when DOM is ready
Meteor.startup(function(){
  $.getScript("//ad.leadboltmobile.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=00000000",function(){
    // script loaded here !
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting this now: "Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened."

Answer (score 1):

we can load js files in meteor i couple of ways

1) using irlibloader package

```
Router.route('codeEditor',{
    waitOn: function(){
        return [IRLibLoader.load('https://some-external.com/javascript.js'), IRLibLoader.load("smthels.js")]
    }
  });
```

2)as said above using getscript

```
 $.getScript("'https://some-external.com/javascript.js", function() {
    //callbcak function
  });
```

I think, using script tag in the head section will load the file in all pages

More Info: http://www.meteorsnippets.com/blog/add-external-scripts-in-meteor